# What are the most comprehensive APIs for cryptocurrency market data?

Tags: api, historical-trade-data

I'm looking for a well documented, easy to use API that provides data on the majority of cryptocurrencies. That data should include the 1 hr, 24hr, and 7 day price changes, as well as the entire history of the volume, and price for each crypto. I've looked into some APIs but none have provided this sort of comprehensive information. There are many great sites that have access to this sort of data, so it must be out there. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested too, did you find a good alternative? maybe something free for commercial use?

Comment: Lots of good info below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most exchanges offer API solutions for market data. Here are some examples:

1. [GDAX](https://docs.gdax.com/#api)
2. [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com/home/api)
3. [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/help/api)
4. [WAVES DEX](http://marketdata.wavesplatform.com/)

CryptoCompare has an API that aggregates data from many exchanges, and they also offer many query parameters. Link: [CryptoCompareAPI](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api)

Additionally, many block explorers provide APIs for blockchain account information.
This [ZChain Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xqlYVdBKoKDOXsN4su8iqrU) shows how to use PowerShell to query the ZChain ZCash block explorer API.

Comment: Also consider the [HitBTC API](https://api.hitbtc.com/) supporting REST and WebSocket too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something simple and fast with a huge amount of coins try https://chasing-coins.com/api/

Comment: Fabulous, just what I needed kind sir!

Answer (score 3):

Cofounder & developer here, you can check our site [coinpaprika.com API](https://api.coinpaprika.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [CoinAPI](https://www.coinapi.io) data provider, which have full coverage of the cryptocurrency markets and provide data via REST, WebSocket and FIX protocols.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [Coinograph](http://coinograph.io) cryptocurrency API. It provides raw trade data, candles, orderbook and ticker.

Disclaimer: I've built the product.

Answer (score 1):

CryptoCompare API is the most comprehensive free api that I can find of.

Links:

1. https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/
2. https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

Answer (score 1):

check out cryptoquote.io

this real-time data feed provides access to real-time streaming price data from the cash exchanges and liquidity providers for institutional order flow as well as historical database, market metrics, logo API and widgets.

Built by my team

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the following API. Although it's mainly used to get standardized coin symbols across exchanges, you also get additional coin data in the response:

- [https://CryptoStandardizer.com](https://cryptostandardizer.com)

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why you're recommending this site and by answering in detail, whether all the features the asker is looking for are present.

Answer (score 1):

You can try CoinGecko api, they provide like comprehensive data. More than you will ever need. https://www.coingecko.com/api/docs/v3

Comment: My absolute favorite! Really nice API.

Answer (score 0):

at Kaiko (www.kaiko.com) we are able to provide you with this comprehensive datasets.
We are a market data infrastructure company since our creation in 2014 and provide trade data, order books and aggregated data (ohclv, vwap, count). We already work with funds, academics, and individual traders and are currently growing fast.
Happy to speak with any of you that have data requirements, just contact us via our website.

Full disclosure: I work at Kaiko :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is best, they don't have restrictions https://www.coinlore.com/cryptocurrency-data-api

Answer (score 0):

Almost each crytpo exchange has its own API, you can integrate it for free and get the data. The first challenge that they are too many (more than 200 exchanges so far), that means 200+ API integrations which cost a lot of time. The second challenge is that these exchanges provide a lot of data and after start collecting you will need to take care of many TBs which is an additional servers cost.

That's why there are such services like Coinmarketcapi professional API, coinapi and CryptoAPIs.io

I made a compare and i picked https://cryptoapis.io/ because they have more exchanges, more options and cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Founder & developer of https://tardis.dev  here. It's an API I've built that provides high frequency cryptocurrency historical raw market data — tick-by-tick trades, full order book depth snapshots & delta updates, quotes, liquidations and more available via HTTP and WebSocket API. Based on that data you can build OHLC candles, volume bars, dolar bars etc.

Answer (score -1):

We use https://bitdataset.com/api/ It is free for our tasks.