# Displaying price in ETH based on USD exchange rate

Tags: ethereum

How do i get the ETH rate in USD, and stored in a variable in php?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60134/what-are-the-most-comprehensive-apis-for-cryptocurrency-market-data

Answer (score 0):

There are an huge number of different sources, for instance [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/) have all the existing coins with the relative value in dollar, computed by averaging over many exchanges.

Comment: Ok... Please, how do i get and store the value of this crypto in a variable using php. So i can use as i deem fit.. A simple line of code or more, will be greatly appreciated.